# How to set value from server side code to an asp.net TextBox with TextMode=“Time”? The time value comes from SQl Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
SqlCommand comEData = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM election WHERE id=" + eid);
DataTable dtElection = edb.GetDataSetFromElectionDB(comEData);

TextBoxStartTime.Text = (TimeSpan.Parse(Convert.ToString(dtElection.Rows[0]["start_time"]))).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStartTime" ReadOnly="true" TextMode="Time" CssClass="textField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: What is your problem _exactly_? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result? What is the type and value of `dtElection.Rows[0]["start_time"]`?

Comment: I searched on google but couldnt found single link for assigning value from code behind

Comment: I want to asssign time value from code behind to to textbox with textmode property Time

Comment: No exception it just doesnt come in the output textbox remains empty with placeholder --:-- --

Comment: Are you sure that your query returns any data?

Comment: yes i am sure about that i have tried printing it on label

Comment: dtElection.Rows[0]["start_time"] this returns object type with value of time from sql Server

Comment: @VivekSalvi And what is the value exactly ot it?

Comment: @SonerGönül the value is 12:32:00.0000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest;

- Define your `start_time` column as [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) *even* if it is not.
- You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) when you generate your sql command. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- If your column is `time`, you don't need to parse it to `TimeSpan`, you need just explicitly casting.

```
(TimeSpan)dtElection.Rows[0]["start_time"]
```

- Also a `TimeSpan` can't be represented with am or pm designator. Those designators can be used with `DateTime` structure.

Comment: how should I assign this to textfield with textmode=time?? As it isor should I use some formatting string??It is not Taking as it is TextBoxStartDate.Text = (TimeSpan)dtElection.Rows[0]["start_time"]; this shows error

Comment: @VivekSalvi You need to use `ToString` method also with `"hh\\:mm"` format.

Comment: Now it is showing me this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Sorry that just executed my last build.Thank you so much buddy it worked

Comment: @VivekSalvi Glad to help.