# Set value from server side code to an asp.net TextBox with type=“Time”?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to assign value to HTML5 text box of type="Time" from code behind of asp.net c#.

HTML Part :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" type="time"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind :

```
txtStartTime.Text = myObj.StartTime;
```

StartTime is a string variable and always contains time as a string. After loading page text box shows no value. But using firebug it shows there are value.

[image]

I have checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838813/how-to-set-value-from-server-side-code-to-an-asp-net-textbox-with-textmode-time).

Answer (score 0):

you are using c# TextBox not HTML5 TextBox. in your HTML part you've used property        `type="time"`
i think there is no property `type`. There is property `TextMode`. `type` is for HTML TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get it. But I need the html5 time picker in my asp textbox and value will be set from server end. what can I do ? any suggestion ?

Comment: this is what you want http://prnt.sc/acabs7. right? you need to make changes to your html